# Minlos-Sazanov theorem on Banach Spaces

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\phi: H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a positive definite complex-valued continuous functional. Then the Minlos-Sazanov theorem asserts that the following are equivalent:

- $\phi$ is the Fourier transform of a finite Borel measure on $H$
- there is a symmetric trace class linear operator s.t. $\phi$ is continuous w.r.t. the norm $\Vert x \Vert := \sqrt{\langle Sx, x \rangle}$ for every $x \in H$.

It is a generalization of the classical Bochner theorem for the Fourier transform of finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am looking for some similar characterization in the case where $H$ is just Banach and not Hilbert, or even whether anything can be said in that case.

Comment: Possibly take a look at the following: http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_1981__17_1_1_0.pdf